I'm Going to Switzerland for 1 week office trip and wish to take my wife along who is a Dependant, we are Indian passport holders living in USA
I'm Going to Switzerland for a 1 week office trip and wish to take my wife along who is a Dependant, we are Indian passport holders living in USA, we would be applying for a schengen Visa together, will there be any issue in the same ? what details should i mentioning

Avoid using dependant on immigration. It may sound disrespectful in Europe (it is ok for non-working minors).

@GiacomoCatenazzi how would one designate a non-working spouse?  It also seems to be the term of choice to describe parents and grandparents who aren't self-sufficient, at least if the English version of directive 2004/38/EC is any guide.

@phoog: For children and grandparent, the person with money may take decisions for them, so the "dependant". Husband and wife are different. One cannot take important decisions (or huge expenses) without all parts agree. They share income (from Swiss laws). So when approaching immigration (and in general people), better not to treat wife and children as slaves (or disregardful). And we see often such behaviour (just do not do abroad). It is a cultural thing

@GiacomoCatenazzi "Dependent" is a perfectly normal English immigration term for family members sponsored by the primary applicant, it does not imply any disrespect. In the OP's case, if their wife is not working and would not qualify for a visa on their own, they have to be designated as a dependent.
